# Open/Libre Office Writer: Display line numbers in frames only

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I'm writing a report in which I have to explain some programming code. I'm putting bits of code into a frame so I can place it nicely around the text. I would like to number the lines in the frame. As far as I can tell the Line Numbering tool only allows you to display line numbers in the general document, and not a particular frame.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this? A plugin to recommend perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using different **paragraph styles** for the frame content and the main text:

1. Enable line numbering for the complete document (Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Line Numbering...`"; don't forget to enable counting of "`Lines in text frames`"):

   [image: Line Numbering dialog]
2. Assign a **custom paragraph style** to the **frame content**;
3. **Disable line numbering for the default paragraph style**, and **enable it only for the custom style used in frames**. On the **"`Outline and Numbering`" tab** of the paragraph style properties, you can **enable / disable the line numbering for the current paragraph style**:

   [image: paragraph style properties]

As **result**, line numbers will only appear at the text paragraphs in the frames:

[image: resulting text document]

### EDIT:

Take care to set an appropriate value for left spacing (Frame Properties -> "`Borders`" tab -> "`Spacing to contents`" setting), to make sure there's enough space left of the content to display the line numbers.